# Filtering based on optional data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have a messaging system with three tables: Event_Types, Messages, and Event_Subscription.  All messages have an event type, and each event type can have 0 or more subscriptions.  In the Event Subscription table are a set of columns that can be used to further filter the messages coming in.  So if i set Src to a non-null value in Event_Subscription, I am saying that I only want messages with that event types from that particular source.

Currently, our query is writer such that for each column, we check if it's null, and if it isn't we filter the message by that column.  I am fairly certain that this isn't going to perform well, especially since our actual prod version will have 11 different columns to filter by.

My question is, is there a more performant way to filter the messages table by the event subscriptions table?

---

**example**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#event_types') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #event_types

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#messages') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #messages

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#event_subscription') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #event_subscription


CREATE TABLE #event_types
(
    PK_EventTypeID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EventTypeName VARCHAR(50)
)



CREATE TABLE #messages
(
    PK_MessageID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FK_EventTypeID INT NOT NULL,
    Src VARCHAR(50),
    [Version] VARCHAR(50)
)


CREATE TABLE #event_subscription
(
    PK_EventSubscriptionID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FK_EventTypeID INT NOT NULL,
    SubScriberID INT NOT null,
    Src VARCHAR(50) null,
    [Version] VARCHAR(50) null
)


INSERT INTO #event_types ( EventTypeName )
VALUES ('Insert'), ('Update'), ('Delete')


INSERT INTO #event_subscription
(
    FK_EventTypeID,
    SubScriberID,
    Src,
    [Version]
)
VALUES
( 1, 1000, null, null ), /* all inserts */
( 2, 1001, 'System A', '1.0.0' ) /*All updates from System A with version 1.0.0*/



INSERT INTO #messages ( FK_EventTypeID, Src, Version )
VALUES
( 1, 'System A', '1.0.0' ),
( 1, 'System B', '2.0.0' ),
( 2, 'System A', '1.0.0' ),
( 2, 'System B', '2.0.0' )


SELECT *
FROM #messages m
    INNER JOIN #event_types et
        ON m.FK_EventTypeID = et.PK_EventTypeID
    INNER JOIN #event_subscription es
        ON m.FK_EventTypeID = es.FK_EventTypeID
WHERE (es.Src IS NULL OR m.Src = es.Src)
    AND (es.[Version] IS NULL OR m.[Version] = es.[Version])
```

Comment: Are there ever going to be any `EventTypes` that don't have a matching row in `event_subscription`?   (thus the outer join)?

Comment: @TabAlleman good catch!  in the actual production data that's a possibility, but unlikely.  i've updated the example to make it an inner join